# How to convert code into static library in xcode 4x

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4

What are the steps to convert code files into static library in xcode 4x.

Comment: Here's a [reference](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/) on creating and using static libraries in Xcode 4

Answer (score 4):

For a new project, you can use the **Cocoa Touch Static Library** template.

For an existing project, you have to add a **Cocoa Touch Static Library** target. To do that, Select the menu **File > New > Target** and choose the **Cocoa Touch Static Library** template.

Then, you will have to add the the appropriate frameworks and resources in the **Build Phases** tab of the target.

[image]